# What material can I use to block a capacitive touch from registering?

Tags: switches, capacitive

I am a self proclaimed tinkering problem solver, but this one has me absolutely stumped!

I have a capacitive touch switch panel with six touch areas that close or open a relay to supply power to various accessories on my motorcycle (fog lights, driving lights accent LEDs...).  The problem is the touch is registering from both the front of the panel and the back of the panel where it is mounted.

How do I block the back from being sensed?  The back is picking up the disrupted grid from the mounting bracket (and other items that get too close) and causing the relay to close and open without me touching it.

I have tried dense rubber sheet, sheet metal of various types, silicone rubber...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The most effective solution would be to disconnect the electrodes on the back. But it probably will require to cut the electric track in a quite definitive way (although you still could repair that). Perhaps the most convenient solution would be to add thick layers of rubber tap on the back panel. The touch sensor has a range of detection, hence the layer need to be more thick than this range. That's why it did not worked when you tried it, you probably used a too thin layer. And when I say a thick layer, it could be really thick depending on your sensor (it could take several centimeters).

Comment: And do not use a conductive layer (like a sheet of metal), this does not work well with capacitive sensor, as it could be detected by the sensor and do the opposite of what you want.

Comment: And remember, the goal is to prevent your finger or any other object from approching too close to the sensor. Whatever you could place between the sensor and your finger, it will be triggered as long as your finger is close enough to the sensor (meaning, is in the sensor detection range) . Another solution could be to screw a few centimeters thick wood panel over your back panel. It could be as simple as that. If you do not have enough space to add several centimeters of thickness to your panel, you should really consider to cut the electric track connecting the electrodes on the back panel.

Comment: try a metal sheet,

Comment: I agree with @Jasen, but make sure to connect it to a fixed voltage (don't leave it floating).

Comment: Covering a sheet of metal and connecting it to the circuit ground from a single point may help. Please note that a metal sheet touching the track coming from a touchpad can make it act as a proximity sensor, thus making it even worse for your needs. So, just connect it to the circuit ground.

Comment: Thank you Jasen23, Wheatley and Rohat Kılıç...  Problem solved.  The base plate the capacitive sensor is mounted to was not grounded.  Using all of your suggestions adding an air gap and grounding the mounting plate to the same circuit fixed the problem!